# Using pydantic to deserialize sublasses of a model

Tags: python, pydantic

I'm using data that follows a class inheritance pattern...  I'm having trouble getting `pydantic` to deserialize it correctly for some use cases.

Given the code below, it appears that the validators are not called when using the `parse_*` methods.  The type for "fluffy" and "tiger" are `Animal`, however when deserializing the "bob" the `Person`, his pet is the correct `Dog` type.

Is there another way to approach this problem?  Using `pydantic` is not a requirement, but the ability to deserialize nested complex types (including `List` and `Dict` of objects) is.

```py
# modified from the following examples
# - https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/2177#issuecomment-739578307
# - https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/619#issuecomment-713508861

from pydantic import BaseModel

TIGER = """{ "type": "cat", "name": "Tiger the Cat", "color": "tabby" }"""
FLUFFY = """{ "type": "dog", "name": "Fluffy the Dog", "color": "brown", "breed": "rottweiler" }"""

ALICE = """{ "name": "Alice the Person" }"""
BOB = f"""{{ "name": "Bob the Person", "pet": {FLUFFY} }}"""

class Animal(BaseModel):
    type: str
    name: str
    color: str = None

    _subtypes_ = dict()

    def __init_subclass__(cls, type=None):
        cls._subtypes_[type or cls.__name__.lower()] = cls

    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(cls):
        yield cls._convert_to_real_type_

    @classmethod
    def _convert_to_real_type_(cls, data):
        data_type = data.get("type")

        if data_type is None:
            raise ValueError("Missing 'type' in Animal")

        sub = cls._subtypes_.get(data_type)

        if sub is None:
            raise TypeError(f"Unsupport sub-type: {data_type}")

        return sub(**data)

class Cat(Animal, type="cat"):
    hairless: bool = False

class Dog(Animal, type="dog"):
    breed: str

class Person(BaseModel):
    name: str
    pet: Animal = None

tiger = Animal.parse_raw(TIGER)
print(f"tiger [{tiger.name}] => {type(tiger)} [{tiger.type}]")

fluffy = Animal.parse_raw(FLUFFY)
print(f"fluffy [{fluffy.name}] => {type(fluffy)} [{fluffy.type}]")

bob = Person.parse_raw(BOB)
pet = bob.pet
print(f"bob [{bob.name}] => {type(bob)}")
print(f"pet [{pet.name}] => {type(pet)}")
```

Output:

```sh
tiger [Tiger the Cat] => <class '__main__.Animal'>
fluffy [Fluffy the Dog] => <class '__main__.Animal'>
bob [Bob the Person] => <class '__main__.Person'>
pet [Fluffy the Dog] => <class '__main__.Dog'>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer from [pydantic project discussion](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/discussions/3091):

You can simply add

```py
class Animal(BaseModel):
    ...
    
    @classmethod
    def parse_obj(cls, obj):
        return cls._convert_to_real_type_(obj)
```